# Can I give light or texture to a 3D Object with flutter_cube package?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies, dart-null-safety

[Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wSP7.png)

This Is What I Want it to be:

[Chair Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88HAf.png)

This Is My Code:

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
          child: Cube(
            onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
              scene.world.add(Object(
                  fileName: "assets/cha/Furniture_Chairs-Stools-Benches_Fritz-Hansen_FriT-JH5.zip.obj"));
              scene.camera.zoom = 10;
            },
          )
      )
  ),
);
```

This Is The Result:

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N35Mw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the `.mtl` file, I used flutter_cube yesterday, and it worked well, but it can't load the `normal_mapping` image (its work don't include load Bump in the `.mtl` file)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Currently your object is not being lit by light.

Set the parameter lighting to true.

```
  return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
          child: Cube(
            onSceneCreated: (Scene scene) {
              scene.world.add(Object(
                  fileName: "assets/cha/Furniture_Chairs-Stools-Benches_Fritz-Hansen_FriT-JH5.zip.obj",
                  lighting: true,));
              scene.camera.zoom = 10;
            },
          )
      )
  ),
);
```